# Using BC547 instead of S8050

Tags: gate-driving, buck-boost

I found this schematic on a website. This is a buck converter. They used S8050 as the gate drive transistor. Can I use BC547 instead of that?

[image: gate driving with bjt]

Comment: Which ever BJT you use, it won't fix the inherent problem in this poor design.

Comment: Yes, it will behave very similarly (note that the pinout is typically not the same). However, as Andy says, it is not a good circuit.

Comment: This will not work at all, because the P-MOSFET has swapped D and S, so Vout is close to Vin all the time, with or without the BJT or even the Arduino.

Comment: f we assume that you understand to swap the D and S of the mosfet it will still not become a good design. 100 mH is a big inductor. Getting one with reasonable small resistance is not trivial. 1N4001 turns OFF very slowly. 10 kOhm resistor turns the mosfet OFF very slowly. The switching frequency should be very low. when compared to the usual, say 40 kHz. This may have some value as learning exercise if one has also proper tuition + laboratory, but as a power supply it's 100% useless. Do not believe any schematics you find in web if you cannot verify it from other sources or by applying math.

Comment: It will work exactly the same with either BJT--that is, it will not work at all because the body diode of your PMOS will always be conducting.

Comment: I did it on my breadboard with a 65w old smps and my breadboard burned sorry guys I am an idiot

Answer (score 0):

The 6-12V in will likely damage your Arduino board.

If you use a BC547, connect Emitter to VIN (red wire); Collector to the inductor/diode. Put 100 Ω in series with the NPN collector and connect the PNP base to that. Replace the 10 kΩ with 100 Ω.

There will be a lot of ripple on the output; make the 100 uF as large as you can (e.g. 1000 uF).

The circuit won't work very well; best to only use frequencies < 10 kHz. Try with 50 % duty cycle for the NPN base drive; you should see an output voltage of about VIN/2.

Comment: Old question, but you mention a PNP transistor and I don't see any in the schematic.